# Unable to initialize REST resources Error when trying to run kafka connect, connecting to Azura data storage sink on docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm running docker with zookeeper, kafka, kafka-connect and azure-storage-sink.
zookeeper and kafka run successfully but kafka-connect and azure-storage-sink containers exit with this error:

```
[2023-08-17 10:04:47,923] ERROR Failed to start Connect (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed)
2023-08-17 13:04:47 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unable to initialize REST resources
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeResources(RestServer.java:297)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect.start(Connect.java:54)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:149)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:83)
2023-08-17 13:04:47 Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-30cd738c==org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer@248c5413{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=true,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STARTED}
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:650)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:415)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:774)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeResources(RestServer.java:295)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     ... 3 more
2023-08-17 13:04:47 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:64)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:172)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:156)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.<init>(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:124)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.newJaxrsResourceAndProviderListener(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:96)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:903)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:864)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:773)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1216)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1187)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1183)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$RuntimeConfigConfigurator.init(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:294)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4390)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:294)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:261)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:339)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
2023-08-17 13:04:47     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:632)
```

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper: 
    hostname: zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    networks:
      - app-network
      
  kafka:
    hostname: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:29092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: false  # Disable auto topic creation
      
    networks:
      - app-network

  kafka-connect:
    hostname: kafka-connect
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
    container_name: kafka-connect
    environment:
      - CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:29092
      - CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083
      - CONNECT_GROUP_ID=connect-cluster
      - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-configs
      - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-offsets
      - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-status
      - KAFKA_CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_CONNECT_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
      - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=INFO
      - CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars
      - CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka-connect  # Replace with your Kafka Connect host name
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    volumes:
      - ./jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - app-network

  azure-storage-sink:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
    container_name: azure-storage-sink
    environment:
      - CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:29092
      - CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083
      - CONNECT_GROUP_ID=connect-cluster
      - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-configs
      - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-offsets
      - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=connect-status
      - CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars
      - CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=INFO
      - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      - CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka-connect  # Replace with your Kafka Connect host name
      - AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=<connection_string>
      - TOPICS=
      - TRANSFORMS=route
      - TRANSFORMS.route.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
      - TRANSFORMS.route.regex=.*   # This regex matches all records
      - TRANSFORMS.route.replacement=destination-prefix/${topic}  # Replace with your desired prefix
    volumes:
      - ./jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - kafka-connect
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I would like to run the docker and have all the containers run successfully.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It is always recommended to use a pinned docker image like `7.4.1` since `latest` is subject to change, and your error may not be reproducible